# Android iosched project error

Tags: android, googleio

I downloaded iosched project for io 2012, but the problem once imported the project to Eclipse I get import com.google.android.apps.iosched.R; cannot be resolved.

I researched about and I found that ../libprojects/abs library under android target in the project properties marked with red mark which means it can't be resolved.

Please advice regarding this error.

Thanx for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check that the library path to the abs  lib is setup correctly, if you checked out the project via git recently, both the iosched and a directory called abs should be present in the same directory where you were sitting when you pulled the git repo. To solve this kind of problem, Right click on the project folder in the project explorer on the left in eclipse, go to Project properties, then click on Android in the left pane, then under the build target pane is Library thing, if the library shoes up in red, delete it and add it afresh using the buttons on the right of that pane. That did it for me, seems the path to abs was not set up correctly.